# How do I create a text file in jupyter notebook, from the output from my code

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

How can I create and append the output of my code to a txt file? I have a lot of code.

This is just a small example of what I'm trying to do:

```
def output_txt():
  def blop(a,b):ans = a + b
            print(ans)
        blop(2,3)
        x = 'Cool Stuff'
        print(x)


def main(x):
    f = open('demo.txt', 'a+')
    f.write(str(output_txt))
    f.close
    
main(x)

f = open('demo.txt', 'r')
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
```

But the output gives me this:

cool bananas<function output_txt at 0x0000017AA66F0F78><function output_txt at 0x0000017AA66F0B88><function output_txt at 0x0000017AA66F0948>

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to save the output of your code to a text file, you can add this to a Jupyter notebook cell (the variable `result` holds the content you want to write away):

```
with open('result.txt', 'a') as fp:
    fp.write(result)
```

If you want to convert your whole Jupyter notebook to a txt file (so including the code and the markdown text), you can use [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). For example, to convert to reStructuredText:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to rst notebook.ipynb
```